# Flutter keep textfield focus on layout changes

Tags: flutter, focus

I have a flutter page with a textfield, which has a completely different layout depending on whether I am in landscape or portrait orientation.

Here is a trimmed-down version of my code:

```
  // These are actually created in initState and destroyed in dispose
  TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();
  FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Build for small screens, like landscape
    if ((MediaQuery.of(context).size.height) < 600) {
      return Material(
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              child: Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(24),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text("Title),
                      TextFormField(
                        focusNode: _focusNode,
                        controller: passwordController,
                        key: ValueKey("password_dialog"),
                      )
                    ],
                  )
              )
          )
      );
    }
    return AlertDialog(
      title: "Title",
      content: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: ListBody(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                  child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        focusNode: _focusNode,
                        controller: passwordController,
                        key: ValueKey("password_dialog"),
                     )
                  )
              ),
            ],
          )
      ),
      actions: ...
    );
  }
```

This means, when the screen is rotated the widget tree changes completly.

Unfortunately, when this happens my textfield also loses focus.

How can I prevent this from happening?
I already have a key and a focus node on the textfield, but that does not help.

Comment: Can you provide us the code?

Comment: I added a trimmed down version of the code

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I will post my solution below in case it is still relevant for you.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are using two completely different trees to layout your text field in and the widget-to-element matching algorithm in Flutter goes one level at a time (so it will wash out the previous state before it will figure out that some widget still needs it), you can use a GlobalKey to persist the state between builds.

Below is an example that just should work in your case (based on your code):

```
class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  Test({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  GlobalKey _textFieldKey;
  FocusNode _focusNode;

  @override
  initState() {
    _textFieldKey = GlobalKey();
    _focusNode = FocusNode();
    super.initState();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if ((MediaQuery.of(context).size.height) < 600) {
      return Material(
          child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              child: Container(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
                      MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(24),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text("Title"),
                      TextFormField(
                        focusNode: _focusNode,
                        key: _textFieldKey,
                      )
                    ],
                  ))));
    }

    return AlertDialog(
        title: Text("Title"),
        content: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ListBody(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
                child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      focusNode: _focusNode,
                      key: _textFieldKey,
                    ))),
          ],
        )),
        actions: []);
  }
}
```

This topic is explained thoroughly here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kn0EOS-ZiIc